# Unexpected token 'u' in NodeJS

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js

I am making a ticketing system where I collect the index of the seats in array but when collecting with Node it is collected as an Object which I parse using `JSON.parse`.

Here's the code from the controller of my Angular Controller

```js
  $scope.bookThisSeat = function(seatIndex){

    console.log(seatIndex);
    $scope.ticket.selectedSeats.push(seatIndex);
    console.log($scope.ticket)
  }

  $scope.registerTicket = function(){
    $scope.ticket.selectedBus = $scope.ticket.selectedBus.id;
    $scope.ticket.selectedSeats = angular.toJson($scope.ticket.selectedSeats);
    console.log($scope.ticket);
    $http.post('/tickets/create',$scope.ticket).
    success(function(data){
      if(data.success){
        console.log("success")
      }

    }).
    error(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

And here's my node JS function to collect the input data

```js
  collect: function(req,res,next){
    var fields = ['id','departure','destination','depDate','desDate','selectedSeats','amount','passenger_name','phone','selectedBus'];
    var reqdata = {};
    fields.forEach(function(entry){
      if(typeof req.body[entry] !=='undefined')
        reqdata[entry] = sanitize(req.body[entry]);
      if(typeof req.query[entry]!== 'undefined')
        reqdata[entry] = sanitize(req.query[entry]);
      if(typeof req.params[entry] !== 'undefined')
        reqdata[entry] = sanitize(req.params[entry]);
    });
    reqdata.selectedSeats = JSON.parse(reqdata.selectedSeats);
    req.saf_tktdata = reqdata;
```

It works fine when I am collecting all the data, but it returns an
`Unexpected error u` whenever I want to only collect the `depDate` or `desDate` fields.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess "Unexpected error u", the `u` in that error log means `undefined`

when you collect all the data, `reqdata.selectedSeates` is not `undefined`

but when you collect `depDate` or `desDate` only, probably `reqdata.selectedSeates` is `undefinded` and it cannot be `JSON.parse`

so a quick fix is

```
reqdata.selectedSeats = reqdata.selectedSeats ? JSON.parse(reqdata.selectedSeats) : null;
```