# Unexpected toke u NodeJs

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js, npm

i have a problem with http request to [forecast.io](http://forecast.io),
if call a request normally with **$.ajax** its works well, also if i call the request with [ajax-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajax-request) module gives me that output:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/rawnly/Documents/Github/weather/forecast.js:11:21)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:346:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

## **Here the code**

```
const request = require('ajax-request');
const token = "**********";
const chalk = require('chalk');

request({
  url: `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/5884bb7f746da897d43f2189e5f3221a/49,12`,
  method: "GET",
  data: {
     format: "json"
  },
}, function(err, res, body) {
  if ( err ) {
    console.log( chalk.red(err) );
  }
  if ( res ) {
    console.log( chalk.red(res) );
  }

  if ( body !== undefined ) {
    var data = body ? JSON.parse(body) : body;
    console.log(data); // the output is undefined... :(
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: error output is => `Error: socket hang up`

### Before flag as duplicate

I've alreasy seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38802937/unexpected-token-u-in-nodejs) question and others but doesn't works...

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(body)` to see whether the API is returning what you expect?

Comment: @Aurora0001 Yes, always "undefined"

Comment: Try logging `err` and `res` as well - it probably means an error occurred.

Comment: `Error: socket hang up` that's the output of `err`

Comment: For some reason, the server is refusing to respond to your request. What happens when you go to `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/5884bb7f746da897d43f2189e5f3221a/49,12?format=json` in your browser?

Comment: gives me `Not found` :/

Comment: That explains it. For me, the link works perfectly, so I suspect you're either having network problems or you're blocked from the site. I would contact them and ask for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the support @Aurora0001

Comment: one moment, now if i visit it from browser ( `https://api.darksky.net/forecast/5884bb7f746da897d43f2189e5f3221a/49,12`) works... but if i visit the url you writed gives `not found`..

Comment: So without the `?format=json` it works? If so, just get rid of `data: {
     format: "json"
  },` in your code and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Aurora0001 nope still got the same error

Comment: I would suggest trying a different requests library (e.g. [request](https://github.com/request/request)) which is better supported to see if that fixes it. Just copy [the example](https://github.com/request/request#super-simple-to-use) and change the URL after installing it and see if you have any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: As suggested by [@Aurora0001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6650102/aurora0001) I've tried with [another library](https://github.com/request/request) and it works fine.